# Passing a Message from a Chrome extension to an Autoit Application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, autoit

I have a Chrome extension that interacts with the Autoit application though `nativeMessaging`. 
 I am using the following code to get a message from Autoit to the extension:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.my_company.my_application');
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  console.log("Received" + msg);
});
```

And I then use this code to try and send a message from the extension to Autoit:

```
  var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "knockknock"});
    port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});

     //or
    chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('com.my_company.my_application',
  { text: "Hello" },
  function(response) {
    console.log("Received " + response);
  });
```

---

But how can I then make the Autoit application evaluate the messages sent from the extension?

Comment: In your AutoIt app you'll need to read and write the messages properly according to the [nativeMessaging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol).

Comment: Also, look at [Chrome UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154439-chrome-udf/) which may cover some of your needs.

Comment: I saw that chrome udf before but it just used to delete the input and output files after getting or posting a message,  that's not the messaging system I need,  thanks anyway